# "Trouble to pronounce words" or "trouble pronouncing words"

Tags: difference, verbs, infinitive-vs-gerund

Do these sentences have exactly the same meaning?

> Young children often have trouble to pronounce words right.
>
> Young children often have trouble pronouncing words right.

I can't understand the difference between *to*+verb and verb+*-ing*.

Comment: I'd prefer *...in pronouncing..* somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two sentences mean the same thing, and will both be understood, but the first sentence is incorrect.

You should use the *-ing* verb here:

> Young children often have *trouble pronouncing* words right.

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trouble) indicates this:

> problems or difficulties  [ + -ing verb ] *Parents often have **trouble finding** good carers for their children.*

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trouble) has this definition, with two examples:

> a condition of doing something badly or only with great difficulty -    *has trouble reading*  -  *has trouble breathing*

To complicate matters slightly, you can sometimes say *trouble to* + *verb*, but the shade of meaning is different.  "Trouble" here has the weaker sense of "effort".  Cambridge puts it like this:

> slight problems or effort.  [ + to infinitive ] *If you took the **trouble to** listen to what I was saying, you'd know what I was talking about.*

Cambridge's American edition has this example:

> inconvenience or effort: *The sweater is a bit large, but I’m keeping it because it’s too much **trouble to** return it.*

For me, "too much trouble returning it" would work as well, but "took the trouble listening to what I was saying" doesn't really work (although "took the trouble of listening" would be fine).